# Getting connect ETIMEDOUT for Axios HTTP Get Request

Tags: node.js, http, axios, azure-functions

So I have an Azure Function that calls Microsoft Maps API and it works (sometimes). However at times it throws this error during the request. Please advise.

My Code:

```
const options = 
{
   host: 'atlas.microsoft.com', //added this later
   headers: { 'x-ms-client-id': client_id }
}

//url to get lat/long
let url = 'https://atlas.microsoft.com/search/fuzzy/json?api-version=1.0&subscription-key=' + subscription_key + '&query=' + address + ' USA'

//make req
let res = await axios.get(url, options)
```

Response/Error:

```
{
"error": {
"message": "connect ETIMEDOUT XX.XXX.XX.XX:XXX",
"name": "Error",
"stack": "Error: connect ETIMEDOUT XX.XXX.XX.XX:XXX\n    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1141:16)",
"config": {
  "url": "https://atlas.microsoft.com/search/fuzzy/json?api-version=1.0&subscription-key=myKey&query=myQuery",
  "method": "get",
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
    "x-ms-client-id": myClientID,
    "User-Agent": "axios/0.19.2"
  },
  "transformRequest": [
    null
  ],
  "transformResponse": [
    null
  ],
  "timeout": 0,
  "xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN",
  "xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN",
  "maxContentLength": -1,
  "host": "atlas.microsoft.com"
},
"code": "ETIMEDOUT"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to my timeout problem was adding

```
host:'atlas.microsoft.com
```

into my headers for all of my calls. 99% of the connection errors went away. I also reached out to Mircosoft support and they said it doesn't matter if you're using S0 or S1 there is no throttling so that shouldn't make a difference. Currently support is investigating why adding the host part into request headers made such a difference. Will update later with their response.

I asked a similar question and figured out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63064393/getting-axios-error-connect-etimedout-when-making-high-volume-of-calls) some additional details.

Answer (score 0):

I saw your request url has `subscription-key`, and I think you don't need `options` any more.

According to my test, your problem is not reproduced. The pricing tiers of my Azure Maps service is S1. So I guess the possible reason for your problem.

[image]

**1. pricing tiers.**

*Suggest: You can change your pricing tiers.*

**2. The service of Azure Map is abnormal.**

*Suggest:  It is recommended to raise a support ticket in portal, ask if there is any abnormal service in this area, and check your service log.*

**Below are my test results.**

I tested it and my test url like `https://atlas.microsoft.com/search/fuzzy/json?api-version=1.0&query=seattle&subscription-key=WCzM8k*******nnSYn4`. I just request via chrome browser and get response.

[image]

And I also test by `axios` and it works fine.

[image]

Comment: I did open a request ticket and a technician is currently looking into it. My calls also work through axios, but its not consistent. Sometimes it doesn't work, for the same request. I even ran a test by making 100 identical calls and 4 of them failed with that ^ error. In no particular order either. I will look into the pricing tiers to see if their are concurrency limits or some quotas I am not aware of.

Comment: @search-learn Ok, if there is a professional reply from the official technical staff, I look forward to sharing with you.