# Getting Axios Error: connect ETIMEDOUT when making high volume of calls

Tags: node.js, https, axios, azure-functions

I get this error when making a lot of calls from my Azure Function. What does this error mean? How to troubleshoot? My guess is I'm running out of TCP sockets? I don't really know how to check that in the Function App menu. However I checked the Logs for the Azure Maps API and there is no record of errors or dropped calls so I think it's definitely an axios/function issue.

I have seen some suggestions to add `Connection:Keep-Alive` header or to even create an axios `instance` and reuse it. However I am not sure if my problem is even related to that.

```
Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 13.107.42.21:443
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1141:16) {   errno: 'ETIMEDOUT',   code: 'ETIMEDOUT',   syscall: 'connect',   address: '13.107.42.21',   port: 443,   config: {
    url: 'https://atlas.microsoft.com/search/fuzzy/json?api-version=1.0&subscription-key= myKey &query=myAddress USA',
    method: 'get',
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
      'x-ms-client-id': 'my client ID',
      'User-Agent': 'axios/0.19.2'
    },
    transformRequest: [ [Function: transformRequest] ],
    transformResponse: [ [Function: transformResponse] ],
    timeout: 0,
    adapter: [Function: httpAdapter],
    xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
    xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
    maxContentLength: -1,
    validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
    host: 'atlas.microsoft.com',
    data: undefined   },   request: Writable {
    _writableState: WritableState {
      objectMode: false,
      highWaterMark: 16384,
      finalCalled: false,
      needDrain: false,
      ending: false,
      ended: false,
      finished: false,
      destroyed: false,
      decodeStrings: true,
      defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
      length: 0,
      writing: false,
      corked: 0,
      sync: true,
      bufferProcessing: false,
      onwrite: [Function: bound onwrite],
      writecb: null,
      writelen: 0,
      afterWriteTickInfo: null,
      bufferedRequest: null,
      lastBufferedRequest: null,
      pendingcb: 0,
      prefinished: false,
      errorEmitted: false,
      emitClose: true,
      autoDestroy: false,
      bufferedRequestCount: 0,
      corkedRequestsFree: [Object]
    },
    writable: true,
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {
      response: [Function: handleResponse],
      error: [Function: handleRequestError]
    },
    _eventsCount: 2,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    _options: {
      protocol: 'https:',
      maxRedirects: 21,
      maxBodyLength: 10485760,
      path: '/search/fuzzy/json?api-version=1.0&subscription-key= myKey &query=myAddress%20USA',
      method: 'GET',
      headers: [Object],
      agent: undefined,
      agents: [Object],
      auth: undefined,
      hostname: 'atlas.microsoft.com',
      port: null,
      nativeProtocols: [Object],
      pathname: '/search/fuzzy/json',
      search: '?api-version=1.0&subscription-key= myKey &query=myAddress%20USA'
    },
    _redirectCount: 0,
    _redirects: [],
    _requestBodyLength: 0,
    _requestBodyBuffers: [],
    _onNativeResponse: [Function],
    _currentRequest: ClientRequest {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 6,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      outputData: [],
      outputSize: 0,
      writable: true,
      _last: true,
      chunkedEncoding: false,
      shouldKeepAlive: false,
      useChunkedEncodingByDefault: false,
      sendDate: false,
      _removedConnection: false,
      _removedContLen: false,
      _removedTE: false,
      _contentLength: 0,
      _hasBody: true,
      _trailer: '',
      finished: true,
      _headerSent: true,
      socket: [TLSSocket],
      connection: [TLSSocket],
      _header: 'GET /search/fuzzy/json?api-version=1.0&subscription-key= myKey &query=myAddress%20USA HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
        'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\n' +
        'x-ms-client-id: my client ID\r\n' +
        'User-Agent: axios/0.19.2\r\n' +
        'Host: atlas.microsoft.com\r\n' +
        'Connection: close\r\n' +
        '\r\n',
      _onPendingData: [Function: noopPendingOutput],
      agent: [Agent],
      socketPath: undefined,
      method: 'GET',
      insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
      path: '/search/fuzzy/json?api-version=1.0&subscription-key= myKey &query=myAddress%20USA',
      _ended: false,
      res: null,
      aborted: false,
      timeoutCb: null,
      upgradeOrConnect: false,
      parser: null,
      maxHeadersCount: null,
      reusedSocket: false,
      _redirectable: [Circular],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
      [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype]
    },
    _currentUrl: 'https://atlas.microsoft.com/search/fuzzy/json?api-version=1.0&subscription-key= myKey &query=myAddress%20USA',
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false   },   response: undefined,   isAxiosError: true,   toJSON: [Function] }
```

Comment: Having a near identical issue on my Azure Function - making 1000+ HTTP calls to the Azure DevOps api.

Comment: @RyanRodemoyer would you mind sharing your code for making the calls.I sort of have figured it out

Comment: Can't readily share the code in it's current state. Any chance you can share your findings without my specific code?

Comment: @RyanRodemoyer let me know if my answer below helped

Answer (score 38, accepted):

So essentially after talking to support for a whole month, they told me I was having SNAT problems. Basically running out of outbound ports... which didn't make sense to me since I was using a single axios instance and sharing it across the board. However after reading the provided documentation I came to the conclusion some additional changes needed to be made.

So I had a file in my main folder (in the wwwroot folder) that was called getAxios.js, this file would create a connection to a base url.

Directory layout:

`-wwwroot`

`--getAxios.js`

`--myFunction`

getAxios.js code:

```
const axios = require('axios')
const https = require('https')
const domain = 'https://atlas.microsoft.com'
let instance

module.exports = function (context)
{
    if (!instance)
    {
        //create axios instance
        instance = axios.create({
            baseURL: domain,
            timeout: 60000, //optional
            httpsAgent: new https.Agent({ keepAlive: true }),
            headers: {'Content-Type':'application/xml'}
        })
    }

    return instance;
}
```

However I didn't have the `timeout` set to anything specific before and I was not specifying `keepAlive:true` . Adding those two additional parameters has fixed my issue.

To explain a little more about the ports being exhausted, when a request is made and keepAlive is false that port connection is closed, but it has a small timeout duration before it can be used again. When you are processing a high volume of requests a bunch of these ports are in this state and can't be used and you end up having this issue. This is what MS support explained to me. I am sure I may be miswording a good bit of the networking aspect.

Comment: @RyanRodemoyer Here is my answer

Comment: Thanks so much!! My function runs successfully for the duration of all calls.

Comment: Very good! I had this problem in my script for a week and I couldn't find the solution! You saved my week! Thanks!

Comment: Thank you so much! We have been banging our heads against the wall for a while on this issue. Using the same HTTPS agent for multiple requests fixed the SNAT port exhaustion issue for us. We also used this resource to confirm the problem root cause: https://www.danielstechblog.io/detecting-snat-port-exhaustion-on-azure-kubernetes-service/

Answer (score 3):

This was a tricky issue, please go through the below link, it is an article authored by Microsoft developers themselves about this issue.

In my case, I was triggering more than 100k nearly parallel API calls and more than 95% of them were getting timed out. I added a fix based on the article with minor tweak and it helped me to stop the timeout issue.

https://azureossd.github.io/2022/03/10/NodeJS-with-Keep-Alives-and-Connection-Reuse/index.html

I have summarized the cause and solution of the issue below:

1. There are only 128 to 160 slots available in a functions app. This is due to their network design.
2. When the available slots are exhausted initially, Axios instance does not wait for slots to become available again and starts to send timeout errors for the remaining requests.
3. The solution is to re-use the slots: meaning wait the pending calls and keep its packages alive till the slots become available again after they are initially used
4. The above step can be achieved by using a package called 'agentkeepalive' and passing keep alive agent options to the axios instance.

NOTE 1: Below code is mostly adapted from the above article except for a minor tweak.(full credits to the article)

```
const Agent = require('agentkeepalive');   
const HttpsAgent = require('agentkeepalive').HttpsAgent;

const keepAliveAgent = new Agent({
    maxSockets: 160,
    maxFreeSockets: 160,
    timeout: 60000,
    freeSocketTimeout: 30000,
    keepAliveMsecs: 60000 });

const httpsKeepAliveAgent = new HttpsAgent({
    maxSockets: 160,
    maxFreeSockets: 160,
    timeout: 60000,
    freeSocketTimeout: 30000,
    keepAliveMsecs: 60000 });

const axiosInstance = axios.create({
    baseURL: config.domain,
    httpAgent: keepAliveAgent,
    httpsAgent: httpsKeepAliveAgent });
```

You can use the above axiosInstance to make required calls without timing out.

NOTE 2: This solution is similar to the one in this page by 'search-learn'. But for yet-to-be-found reason it did not work for me and it did point me in the right direction.

Comment: Confirm that as of today, this is the solution that works ! Thanks a lot @sprash95 ! Thanks search-learn for getting us in the right direction too !

Answer (score 2):

As per @search-learn, I solved my problem by explicitly specifying the `timeout` and `httpsAgent` properties on the Axios instance.

```js
import axios from "axios";
const https = require("https");

const auth: string = Buffer.from(`:${envconfig.PAT}`).toString("base64");
axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = `Basic ${auth}`;
axios.defaults.timeout = 30000;
axios.defaults.httpsAgent = new https.Agent({ keepAlive: true });
```

Comment: Does this work if new axios instance is created for each request?

Comment: @SarveshKumar the whole point of an instance, is to reuse it and not create a new one on each request. So no it would not work

Answer (score 2):

While load testing our application, I faced ETIMEOUT errors due to exhaustion of TCP ports. I use NestJS for our backend. Posting the solution which worked for me.

1. Create a singleton axios instance to use throughout the application.

```js
import axios, { AxiosInstance } from 'axios';
import http from 'node:http';
import https from 'node:https';

export default class AxiosCustomInstance {
  private static instance: AxiosInstance;

  public static getInstance(): AxiosInstance {
    if (!AxiosCustomInstance.instance) {
      const httpAgent = new http.Agent({
        keepAlive: true,
        timeout: 60000,
        scheduling: 'fifo',
      });
      const httpsAgent = new https.Agent({
        keepAlive: true,
        timeout: 60000,
        scheduling: 'fifo',
      });
      AxiosCustomInstance.instance = axios.create({
        httpAgent,
        httpsAgent,
      });
    }

    return AxiosCustomInstance.instance;
  }
}
```

Link for the http/https agent configs: [NodeJS Docs](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v19.x/docs/api/http.html#new-agentoptions)

Now use this class to fetch the axios instance to use anywhere in your application

```js
import AxiosCustomInstance from 'your path';

async yourFunc() {

  await AxiosCustomInstance.getInstance().request({
        method: '',
        url: '',
      });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If someone is using Google Cloud with some kind of VPC + Cloud NAT. Try to increase the reserved port amount on the NAT page. By default it has a minimum of 64 ports, I increased that number and the problem start to disappear.

[image: Cloud Nat config]

Consider combinating this with enabling the `keepAlive` option on Axios for a more proper solution.

Cheers!

Comment: I would say that is not a good approach because increasing ports, is only creating a larger time gap before the issue falls in on you. Essentially delaying the issue and not solving it. However setting min ports higher with the combination of reusing them definitely sounds like a proper approach

Comment: Thats right!, a combination with the axios `keepAlive` option sounds like a proper approach. In my case, even with the keepAlive enabled I was having some errors on high loads, so this combination helps a lot 